# Wordpress: Updating tags in large number of Posts

Tags: wordpress, tags

I have more than 2000 posts and each post contains almost 1000+ tags. Now i want to update all the posts with new additional tags in one go. Is there any simple way??

Regards-

Answer (score 0):

From the dashboard:

- Go to Posts -> All Posts
- Beside Title there is a checkbox, check it and it will check all the boxes down the page.
- Above the checkbox there is a dropdown list, select Edit and press Apply
- You will see an input box called Tags, add the new tag in there
- Next click the update button and those posts will now have the new tag.

I would recommend that you do this for one or two posts first to make sure it will work as you want and not break/mess anything up.

Answer (score 0):

You have one more option, if some of the tags are similar for all the posts. You can post a piece of code in your function.php file and put the list of common tags there :

```
function my_tag_update () {
    GLOBAL $post;
    wp_set_post_tags( $post->ID, 'tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4', true );
}
add_action('publish_post', 'my_tag_update');
add_action('save_post', 'my_tag_update');
```

So, in this case when you create a new post or edit a post, these defined tags will add to it automatically.

Comment: By this method, i will have to create a new post or edit an already existing post.  while in my case, i want to update tags in the posts already existing. 

I have 2000 Posts and each post has 1000+ tags now i want to update these 2000 posts with additional 350 tags.